# Restoring Clonezilla clone images from 2nd partition of USB drive

Tags: linux, partitioning, clonezilla

I know I'm doing 99% of this correct... because 99% of it is working.

I made a 64GB USB drive with 2 partitions:

```
1. FAT32 300MB for Clonezilla Live
2. NTFS 57GB for my clone images
```

I altered Clonezilla's menu to only have 2 choices:

```
A.  Restore this PC
B.  Backup this PC
```

I can boot into Clonezilla, and using "B", save a disk image (about 37GB) into partition #2 /home/partimag folder.
(I later can see it is there.)

(I know 0 about linux, so I'm surprised I got it working this far!)

But when I later try to use "A" to restore, Clonezilla never finds any images.
(It's probably looking at partition 1's empty /home/partimag folder.)

How can I get Clonezilla to look for previous images in partition 2's /home/partimag folder?
(I need to do this with syslinux.cfg menus, NOT making the user read/pick menus.)

Here are some of the non-working things I've tried in **syslinux.cfg** so far:

```
 ocs_live_run="ocs-sr -g auto -e1 auto -e2 -r -j2 -c -src -p choose restoredisk TestImage1 sda" 
 ocs_live_run="ocs-sr -g auto -e1 auto -e2 -r -j2 -c -src -p choose restoredisk ask_user sda"
```

In linux, I assume "home" isn't just another folder called "home", or is it?

I hoping to (eventually) have the "restore menu" ask the user very little.  Perhaps just "confirm this restore".  Not ask the source, nor the destination.

Almost seems like I can freely pick the destination for the resulting image
when doing a SAVE.  (The drive, the folder, and the name.  The 2nd partition
of my thumb drive.)

But when trying to do a RESTORE, it always assumes USB thumb drive, partition
number 1, inside /home/partimag.  Of course, that's empty.

When restoring, I'd be happy with either of these solutions:

```
2nd best:  Ask the user for the drive+dir+name of the image.
1st best:  Use the driveID+dir+name that is listed after the RESTOREDISK option.
```

Am I missing a cmd-line option that would set the "look here for images when doing any restore" choice?

Comment: I'd be very careful using disk labels like "sda" and "sdb" to identify drives, they can change with each boot. I'd use UUID's instead. And how exactly did you alter clonezilla's menu? I'm assuming it's in syslinux.cfg only?

Comment: I just used any text editor to edit syslinux.cfg.  I can find the (non-changing) UUID for the 2nd partition of the USB stick.  But where would that appear in syslinux.cfg?  Also, the UUID for the laptops (restore location) is different for every laptop we try to restore... so the UUID won't help there.

Comment: Interesting, with a different laptop & possibly different number of partitions every boot it's probably safest to show a list of all drives & pick the one(s) to backup / restore. Sorry I don't know the details of clonezilla enough to answer, but I'd search for clonezilla custom usb...?

Comment: There are a huge number of articles about "how to create the 2 partition USB drive", as well as "how to make a backup".   Almost nothing about "when doing a restore... look in /home/partimag on the 2nd partition of the USB drive".  (The very location designed to store the images.)